# Find the first and second derivatives w.r.t. $t:g(t)=f((1-t)\textbf x+t\textbf y)$, where $\textbf x,\textbf y\in\Bbb{R}^n,t\in\Bbb R$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

$$g(t) := f((1-t) {\bf x} + t {\bf y})$$ where ${\bf x}, {\bf y} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $t \in \Bbb R$. Find the first and second derivatives of $g$ with respect to $t$.

---

I'm having trouble with the second derivative more than the first because of the multivariable product rule. I have found the first derivative to be: $g'(t)=(\nabla f((1-t)\textbf x+t\textbf y))^T(\textbf y-\textbf x)$. But I'm not sure of the correct steps for the second derivative.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Ignore the bot.

Comment: Is the output of $f$ a real number or a vector of reals?

Comment: $g'')t)=(y-x)^\intercal \operatorname{Hess}_f(x+t(y-x))(y-x)$. Apply the chain rule a second time. Here $\operatorname{Hess}$ is the Hessian matrix that represents the second derivative of $f$ in standard coordinates $D^2f(x)=(\partial^2_{ij}f(x))$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ has variables $z_1,\dots,z_n$, i.e., we're looking at the function $f(z_1,\dots,z_n)$.  For the problem at hand, we have that $z=(1-t)x+ty$ or that $z_i=(1-t)x_i+ty_i$.

Putting this together, we can calculate the first derivative using the multivariate chain rule of $g$ as
$$
g'(t)=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial f}{\partial z_i}(z)\frac{dz_i}{dt}(t).
$$
By direct observation, we see that $\frac{dz_i}{dt}(t)=y_i-x_i$, so the derivative is
$$
g'(t)=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial f}{\partial z_i}(z)(y_i-x_i)=(\nabla f(z))^T(y-x),
$$
as you wrote.

The second derivative can be calculated similarly,
$$
g''(t)=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial f}{\partial z_i}(z)(y_i-x_i)
=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial z_i\partial z_j}(z)\frac{dz_j}{dt}(t)(y_i-x_i).
$$
By the argument above, this simplifies to
$$
g''(t)=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial z_i\partial z_j}(z)(y_j-x_j)(y_i-x_i).
$$
The second partials form the Hessian, so we have $g''(t)=(y-x)^TH(f)(z)(y-x)$, where $H(f)$ denotes the Hessian of $f$.